# Is this method a good candidate for a service layer?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Should the following `GetPhysicalFileLocation()` method in the `Car` class have its own Service Layer?

```
public class Car
{
    public int id;
    public string model;
    public int year;
    public IList<Pic> lstCarPics;
}
```

Then we have the respective class:

```
public class Pic
{
    public string filename;
    public string fileLocation;
    public string GetPhysicalFileLocation()
    {
        string LocalDirectory = "~\\CarFiles\\";
        DirectoryInfo diPath = new 
            DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server
                         .MapPath(LocalDirectory + car.id);
    }
}
```

Seeing that this method and others will access physical file locations throughout the application, would something like this justify having it's own `FileService`?

I'm having trouble understanding when methods like this should fall under it's own service layer vs leaving it in its class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Vogel612 hinted, a class shouldn't expose its fields publicly - this:

```
public class Car 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
public class Car
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id 
    { 
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

As you can see, encapsulation is easily achieved with auto-properties - don't expose your fields!

---

Method `GetPhysicalFileLocation` has *dependencies* on the file system *and* on an `HttpContext`, so you *definitely* want that to be abstracted away, so you can write a test that uses that code and doesn't *actually* hit the file system.

I'd move it to some `IFileSystemService` implementation:

```
public interface IFileSystemService
{
    string GetPhysicalFileLocation(int carId);

    // ...
}
```

And then make a class that implements it:

```
public class FileSystemService : IFileSystemService
{
    // load this value from application settings?
    private readonly string _localDirectory = "~\\CarFiles\\";

    public string GetPhysicalFileLocation(int carId)
    {
        var diPath = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current
                                                  .Server.MapPath(_localDirectory + carId);
    }
}
```

And now you can have client code like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IFileSystemService _service;

    public MyClass(IFileSystemService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public void DoSomething(int carId)
    {
        var fileName = _service.GetPhysicalFileLocation(carId);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This way you can inject a "fake"/"mock" implementation for `IFileSystemService` and test *DoSomething* without hitting the file system or depending on an `HttpContext`; the key being that depending on the file system and on an `HttpContext`, is an implementation detail that the client code doesn't need to know about.

Comment: Ok.  How would this get "glued" back up?  So then would I have a GetPhysicalFileLocation method within the Pic class that calls the IFileService?

Comment: I'd make a separate class to implement the interface, and have whoever needs to `GetPhysicalFileLocation` call the interface's method (which would take a `fileName`  parameter).

Comment: Ok I'm lost in the code-woods now :( Can you create a quick sample using my code above how this would work?  That's the part I'm not getting.  Thanks!

Comment: @TheTruthIsInCode sorry that was confusing - edited with [hopefully] less confusing details ;)

Answer (score 2):

The convention for public fields and properties in c# is `PascalCasing`. This would make the following:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id; //{ get; set; } this makes it a property.
    public string Model;
    public int Year; 
    public IList<Pic> LstCarPics;
}

public class Pic
{
    public string FileName;
    public string FileLocation;
    //...
}
```

Furthermore there is (from the information you posted) no real necessity to shorten the classname to `Pic`. Why not just use `Picture`?